# Warning: Invalid DOM property `tabindex`. Did you mean `tabIndex`?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set a tabindex in react which giving me a warning   **: "Warning: Invalid DOM property `tabindex`. Did you mean `tabIndex`?"**.

My code is :

```
<Nav.Item key={label}>
      <Nav.Link tabindex={index+1} > Test  </Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
```

When I am using tabIndex there is no error but its not working While I am using like shared code its working but giving warning I want to remove that warning.

Comment: try to convert it to string with adding `+""` and see the result. im not sure ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes in reactjs follow camelCase. Hence the warning.
And use tabIndex in `<Nav.Item`> instead of `<Nav.Link>`

```
<Nav.Item key={label} tabIndex=`${index+1}` >
      <Nav.Link> Test  </Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
```

Check out the https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-sun-n969i

It works perfectly fine when you use `tabIndex` with `<Nav.Item>`

Comment: when I am using like this there is no error but Its also not working properly

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: while you use tab button to handle app it didn't work. I am using https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/ component In which there is no tabIndex

Comment: Check out the sandbox

Answer (score 2):

[Official React docs says](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

> In React, all DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased. For example, the HTML attribute tabindex corresponds to the attribute tabIndex in React. The exception is aria-* and data-* attributes, which should be lowercased. For example, you can keep aria-label as aria-label.

All the DOM attributes in React should be in camelCase. For example,

`className="btn btn-primary"` instead of `classname="btn btn-primary"`.

In your case it should be strictly `tabIndex` instead of `tabindex`